# Fastest way to read 2D matrix

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, multidimensional-array, profiling

I am using a nested dictionary to store a 2D matrix that has known values at the time of initiation and I am finding it too slow to read from. Is there anything faster?

### update

I am not looking for any reason why my code is "not working". It works correctly - but I would like to know of any way to make it faster. The details below are to provide context.

I have also tried flattening out the nested dictionary using a custom class as the key but that was even slower.

### Details

I have a list of 500 - 7,000 objects that I need to store a value against for every possible combination (250,000 - 49,000,000).

Each possible combination has a default value. This value will change based on the dependencies between the objects, and there is on average 1 dependency per object. For each dependency there will be 1 - 100 updates. On average the values will be read 5 times per update.

So for 1 example I have 1,700 objects for 2,890,000 possible combinations, with 1,900 dependencies, meaning 9,500 - 95,000 reads. This example is taking over 90 seconds to calculate!

This is the initialisation code. I'm pretty happy with this part as it builds it in less than a second.

```
var allCombinations = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>();
foreach (var thisObject in allObjects)
{
    var comboFor1Object = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    foreach (var otherObject in allObjects)
    {
        comboFor1Object.Add(otherObject.Id, (thisObject.Id == otherObject.Id ? 0 : 100));
    }
    allCombinations.Add(thisObject.Id, comboFor1Object);
}
```

This is the simplified update part of the code - and this is the stinky slow part. According to the Visual Studio Performance Profiler - it is specifically lines 9,10 and 11 where it reads the dictionary. This method takes 75% of the time of which mscorlib.ni.dll accounts for 52.9% of that.

```
foreach (var myObject in myDependency.Objects)
{
    foreach (var otherObject in myMatchingObjects)
    {
        if (myObject.Id == otherObject.Id)
        {
            continue;
        }
        var existingValue = allCombinations[myObject.Id][otherObject.Id];
        var minValue = allCombinations[myObject.Id][myDependency.FromObjectId] + allCombinations[myDependency.ToObjectId][otherObject.Id] + myDependency.MinValue;
        var maxValue = allCombinations[myObject.Id][myDependency.ToObjectId] + allCombinations[myDependency.FromObjectId][otherObject.Id] -myDependency.MaxValue;
        allCombinations[myObject.Id][otherObject.Id] = Math.Max(Math.Max(existingValue, minValue), maxValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your code for Id, FromObjectId and ToObjectId properties?

Comment: @rs232 Consider them all just properties (Int32)

Comment: Does your list of objects ``allObjects`` change? If not, and if your ``Id`` can be mapped to array indices, consider using a 2D array, that will definitely be faster. Otherwise I'd suggest using ``ValueTuple`` (or, if using an earlier C# version, make your own struct) of ``Id`` by ``Id`` as a key, that way you remove the second layer of dictionaries.

Comment: @dumetrulo `allObjects` does not change. I'd have to do some kind of IndexOf whenever I query the list though, I'll give it a try. I already tried using a class as the key instead of a tuple to remove the 2nd layer of dictionaries, and it was pretty slow. I haven't seen the valuetuple before, I'll try that too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a 2D array as suggested by **dumetrulo** in the comments is twice as fast as using a nested dictionary for reads. Open to ideas about anything faster though!

```
for (int i = 0; i < allObjects.Count; i++)
{
    //new property to record the index in the array
    allObjects[i].Index = i;
}

var allCombinations = new int[allObjects.Count, allObjects.Count];
foreach (var thisObj in allObjects)
{
    foreach (var otherObj in allObjects)
    {
        allCombinations[thisObj.Index, otherObj.Index] = (thisObj.Id == otherObj.Id ? 0 : 100);
    }
}
```

which makes the slow code like this:

```
void DoUpdates(int[,] allCombinations)
{
    .
    .
    foreach (var myObject in myDependency.Objects)
    {
        foreach (var otherObject in myMatchingObjects)
        {
            .
            .
            var existingValue = allCombinations[myObject.Index, otherObject.Index];
            .
            .
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment to the original question, I would create a value type (alternatively, if your C#/.NET version supports `ValueTuple<int, int>`, use that):

```
struct IdById
{
    public int Id1, Id2;

    public IdById(int a, int b)
    {
        Id1 = a; Id2 = b;
    }
}
```

With that, your initialization code should look as follows:

```
var allCombinations = new Dictionary<IdById, int>();

foreach (var thisObj in allObjects)
{
    foreach (var otherObj in allObjects)
    {
        var ids = new IdById(thisObj.Id, otherObj.Id);
        allCombinations[ids] = (ids.Id1 == ids.Id2 ? 0 : 100);
    }
}
```

And your 'stinky slow part':

```
foreach (var myObj in myDependency.Objects)
{
    foreach (var otherObj in myMatchingObjects)
    {
        if (myObj.Id != otherObj.Id)
        {
            var ids = new IdById(myObj.Id, otherObj.Id);
            var existingValue = allCombinations[ids];
            var minValue =
                allCombinations[new IdById(myObj.Id, myDependency.FromObjectId)] +
                allCombinations[new IdById(myDependency.ToObjectId, otherObj.Id)] +
                myDependency.MinValue;
            var maxValue =
                allCombinations[new IdById(myObj.Id, myDependency.ToObjectId)] +
                allCombinations[new IdById(myDependency.FromObjectId, otherObj.Id)] -
                myDependency.MaxValue;
            allCombinations[ids] =
                Math.Max(Math.Max(existingValue, minValue), maxValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Whether this will be faster in the end is something you will have to test…

Comment: I've tested it and the struct is slower - waaaay slower. I overrode the GetHashCode() method which sped it up as the Dictionary needs the hash for the key but still 10x slower.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to c#7 .. yet! Looking forward to it though.